# Grub Background Image Problem

Tags: grub2

My GRUB preview looks like this, where the background image looks so normal & beautiful
[image: preview]

---

But instead, the actual image looks like this. How to solve this problem???
[image: actual]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83287/discussion-on-question-by-krafi-grub-background-image-problem).